# Is just combination layers ensemble model?

Tags: python, keras

I made a machine learning code in keras that is combination of cnn and lstm(merge)

Is just combination layers ensemble model?

```py
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Conv2D, Flatten, concatenate

lstmLayer = LSTM(10)(input)
cnnLayer = Conv2D(10, (3,3)(input)
flatLayer = Flatten()(cnnLayer)
cnnDense = Dense(10)(flatLayer)

concat = concatenate([lstmLayer, cnnDense])

output = Dense(1)(concat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, combining layers is not an ensemble, you can have different layers in one model. Only a combination of fully trained models is an ensemble.

Comment: thank you. did you mean that my_model = model(input, output) is ensemble?

Comment: @SuhwanJi no, that is a single model, an ensemble has multiple models.

Comment: I used lstm and cnn. isn't this multiple models? one output just single?

Comment: No, you are using them as layers, not as full models